# How to tell if a graph is strongly connected using answer set programming?

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I'm new to answer set programming and could use some help. I've been reading [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255668799_A_User's_Guide_to_gringo_clasp_clingo_and_iclingo), but still could use some help. How would I use answer set programming to tell if a graph is strongly connected?

My brainstorming:

- Graph represented by nodes and edges (ie; node(1..2), edge(1,2), and edge(2,1)).
- Now I need rule "strong() :- ......" that is true if the graph is strongly connected.
- A graph is strongly connected if you can start at any node and reach any other node by following the edges in the direction(s) they point.
- So my program needs to take each node X and go along the directed edges to try and reach every other node. True if it reaches every other node, False otherwise.

Strong() :- ?

Comment: You dont need the adverb "strongly". The definition is "An undirected graph is **connected** when it has at least one vertex and there is a path between every pair of vertices." See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29#Connected_graph

Answer (score 0):

First, unless your graph is directed, you have to get the symmetric edges:

```
edge(X,Y):- edge(Y,X).
```

Then, you need to tell that two nodes are connected if there is a path between them:

```
connected(X,Y):- edge(X,Y).
connected(X,Z):- edge(X,Y) ; connected(Y,Z).
```

Now, `strong` holds if for all pairs of nodes, they are connected:

```
strong:- connected(X,Y): edge(X,_), edge(_,Y).
```

An alternative version could be:

```
not_strong:- not connected(X,Y) ; edge(X,_) ; edge(_,Y).
strong:- not not_strong.
```

---

(Tested with clingo 4.5.4)